# How to deploy Deno app on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, deno

I created REST api using `Deno`, everything is working fine. But I couldn't find an option to deploy `Deno` app in Firebase hosting. For Node project we have an option to deploy using [firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set-up-node.js-and-the-firebase-cli).

[image]

What we should do to make it work for Deno project?

Comment: (not a downvoter) Are you asking how to [run a deno app on Google Cloud Functions?](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+deno+on+google+cloud+functions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No In firebase hosting there is an option to run node JS project using firebase functions. I added link here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set-up-node.js-and-the-firebase-cli

Comment: Firebase Functions == Cloud Functions

Comment: Ok :-)), Thanks for the information, Is this question will be helpful for others or not? asking this to delete this question